# Opening a new activity crashes my application

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I do not know if this bug is in the code that I use to open the activity, or if it lies in the activity itself. This is the code for opening the activity, please tell me if I have an error in this, or if it is something else.

```
public void openGallery(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PhotoGallery.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: You must post the crash log for anyone to give you any sort of meaningful help on this. Also it would be helpful to post the code from the `onCreate()` of your `PhotoGallery` Activity, as the issue is likely being generated from within that code.

Comment: Code looks fine. Show your logcat of the crash. Maybe : Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, PhotoGallery.class); will do the trick. And why are you passing a View as Parameter and not using it?

Comment: Please post the crash logs and the  "PhotoGallery" code .

Comment: Specifically that activity, or does any activity cause it? Does multi-tasking out of your app and back in again cause a crash?

Comment: What does the LogCat say when it opens the activity?

Comment: Two things that can be wrong here: 1) PhotoGallery is not an Activity class 2) PhotoGallery activity is not added to AndroidManifest.xml